# Quadratic Equation of uniform random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

[image]

By looking at the mgf, The thing is got to know is that $X \sim U(0,1) $

But how do we find the value if $ \alpha \space  \text{and} \space \beta$ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$X \sim U[0,1]$, $$48X^2-40X+3> 0$$
$$(12X-1)(4X-3) > 0$$

That is $X< \frac1{12}$ or  $X>\frac34$.

Hence $$\alpha = \frac1{12} + \left(1 - \frac34\right)=\frac{1+12-9}{12}=\frac13$$

Now let $Y =\ln X$.

$$Y^2+2Y-3>0$$
$$(Y+3)(Y-1) >0$$
That is $Y<-3$ or $Y>1$ which is equivalent to $X < e^{-3}$ or $X > e$. Hence,

$$\beta = e^{-3}$$
$$\ln \beta = -3$$

$$\alpha - 2 \ln \beta = \frac13 - 2(-3)=6\frac13=\frac{19}{3}$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

You have found the distribution of $X$, so you need to

- solve the inequalities,
- which then gives you the probabilities as the proportion of $[0,1]$ where they are positive
- and thus the value of the expression.

The inequalities are essentially quadratic, and on $[0,1]$ the curves look like this (which you can use to check you have calculated correctly)

[image]